# PayPal and Failing IPN's Issues

Tags: civicontribute

I am currently having issues with PayPal communicating with our website and CiviCRM. Half of the recurring contributions have not shown up over the past couple months and every one-time donation has listed as "Pending/Incomplete Transaction over the past week. Our current version of Civi is 4.4.3. We have checked the URLs and our web host has white-listed all IPN's even though they don't think anything was being blocked. We have also applied a few patches of code from newer versions and we are still having issues. Is anyone else having this problem. This is a bit out of the scope of my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you hosting?

Comment: Liquidweb is our host.

Answer (score 1):

Does Paypal insist on an SSL certificate? Maybe yours is not compliant?

Comment: I know I am having this same issue, and I know for a fact that our SSL is self signed at the moment, so possibly this is the source?

Comment: Yes, most likely. I would confirm with Paypal, it should show in their logs or you could raise a support call with them.

Comment: Can we check logs in PayPal ourselves or do we need to request it to be done?

Comment: In your PayPal account there should be a IPN History page, that should reveal any problems with IPNs in the past.

Comment: any idea where to find that in the new PayPal account view?  The instructions here are for the old version - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/

Comment: I just happened to catch an order hang in the shopping cart as it took place.  I immediately checked the logs and there's no record of the order at all. no failed IPN, nothing.

Comment: There should be something on the Paypal side, in the transaction log theres normally an entry for all the failed payments

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure IPN link correctly in your paypal accunt? Also you need to configure it in your server configuration file.